# Obtaining code param from url

Tags: regex, url

I have urls with the following form:

```
http://localhost:9999/api/users/COD_MALE
http://localhost:9999/api/users/COD_FEMALE
```

I want to obtain match the last param (`COD_MALE` or `COD_FEMALE`)

```
\/api\/users\/^[a-z0-9_-]*$
```

but it does not work.

Comment: As easy as `[^/]+$`. But can't you use any URL parsing features?

Comment: `\/api\/users\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$`

Comment: You could also split around `/` and retrieve the last string of the resulting array if you don't need to validate the `/api/users/` part.

Comment: I need to validate the  `/api/users/`part

Comment: @anubhava Please put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture part after `/api/users/`:

```
/\/api\/users\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$/
```

If your regex flavor allows then use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]:

```
/\/api\/users\/([\w-]*)$/
```